# JUnit Mockito ReflectionEquals on List of Objects

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I need to test if a returned list of objects is the same as the expected value. Since I do not want to override the equals method just for the test im looking for a solution to compare the classes by values. I found the ReflectionEquals class, but this is not working on a list. Is there any other approach to test this?

```
@Test
public void testUseOnFieldWithRuleApplied() {
    List<Field> argumentFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Field(1), new Field(2)));

    List<Field> expectedFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Field(0), new Field(1)));
    List<Field> returnedFields = this.toBeTestedRule.useOnFields(argumentFields);

    assertTrue(new ReflectionEquals(expectedFields).matches(returnedFields));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fest-assert library.

With that library you can write the following:

```
Assertions.assertThat(list1).isEqualTo(list2);
```

But that still relies on equals method of the lists.

Another approach could be to write:

```
Assertions.assertThat(list1).containsExactly(list2.toArray());
```

Or

```
Assertions.assertThat(list1).hasSize(list2.size()).containsSequence(list2.toArray());
```

And that last possibilty (containsSequence) doesn't rely on the equals method of the list.

But, I don't understand why you don't want to rely on the equals method because it should be implemented correctly for every list.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to be in the next AssertJ Core version: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1002

(Iterable/array support)

```
assertThat(returnedFields).usingRecursiveComparison()
                               .contains(new Field(0), new Field(1));
```